# OpenGL restart scene

Tags: c++, c, opengl, glut

I am having a problem with a game that I developed to a class.

The objetive was to make a game were you can kill the square and in the end show the max score and the max velocity but I also want to make the game to restart when the player presses the R key but I can't figure out how to make the opengl restart all the scene.

Here is the code:

**HandleKeyboardFunction, when R is pressed we want to restart the game**

```
void HandleKeyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key) 
    {

        //Sai quando pressionado Qq
        case 113: //q
        case 81: //Q
            exit(0);
            break;
        case 82: //R
        case 114: //r
            LIFE=3;
            SCORE=0;
            Respawn();
            SetupRC();
            Text();
            break;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

**TIMERFUNCTION to move my square**

```
void TimerFunction(int value)
{
        GLfloat velocidade;

        //Controlo do tempo
        t = glutGet(GLUT_ELAPSED_TIME) / 1000.0;
        int time = (int)t;

        //Reverter direção quando a Formiga tocar nas laterais
        if(x1 > windowWidth-rsize || x1 < 0)
            xstep = -xstep;     

        //Reajustamento, no caso de a janela mudar de dimensões.
        if(x1 > windowWidth-rsize)
            x1 = windowWidth-rsize-1;       
        if(y1 > windowHeight-rsize)
            y1 = windowHeight-rsize-1;

        //Mover a "Formiga" aleatoriamente

            Random();

        //Se a "Formiga" fugir, o jogador perde 1 vida.
        if(y1 < -15)
        {
            LIFE--;
            //Quando o jogador perde 1 vida, a velocidade inicial é reestabelecida, assim como o SCORE.
                //*
                xstep = 2.0f; 
                ystep = 2.0f;
                //*
            SCORE=0;
            I=50;
            Respawn();
            num=rand() % 4; //Vai alterar a direção da "formiga" aleatoriamente 
        }

        //O Jogo termina quando acabarem as vidas ao jogador
        if(LIFE<0) 
        {
            glClearColor(1.0f,1.0f,1.0f,1.0f);
            sprintf(gameover, "GAME OVER!!!"); //MENSAGEM DE FIM DE JOGO
            sprintf(resultado,"MAX SCORE: %d | VEL MAX: %.2f ",highscore, max);
            sprintf(menu,"(q) - Sair | (r) - Repetir");
            glutKeyboardFunc(HandleKeyboard);
        }
        else
        {
            glutTimerFunc(33,TimerFunction, 1);
        }

        //Mostra no ecrã, o SCORE, a VIDA e o TEMPO do jogo.
        sprintf(sl, "SCORE : %d | LIFE: %d | TIME: %2d Sec | MAX SCORE: %d ", SCORE, LIFE, time, highscore);

        //Vamos garantir que o jogador ve sempre a velocidade positiva 
            //*
            if(xstep>ystep) 
            { 
                if(xstep<0){velocidade=-xstep;} else {velocidade=xstep;}
            }
                else { if(ystep<0){velocidade=-ystep;} else {velocidade=ystep;}
            }
            //*


        sprintf(vel,"VEL: %.2f ",velocidade); //Mostra a velocidade da "formiga"
        if(velocidade>max){max=velocidade;} //
        if(SCORE>highscore){highscore=SCORE;}; //Garantir que no final é mostrada a melhor pontuação do jogo
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
```

**MAIN**

```
//Main program entry point
int main(void){

            glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
            glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
            glutCreateWindow("ESMAGA FORMIGA");
            glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);
            glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
            glutTimerFunc(33, TimerFunction, 1);
            glutMouseFunc(mouseClick);
            SetupRC();
            glutMainLoop(); //Frame by frame
}
```

Comment: `main` should return `int`. Also, I'd recommend you to delete from the question all code which isn't related to it.

Comment: `glClear` will clear the scene... but why do you want to restart the scene in the first place?

Comment: I edited and now I only show the code that refers to the problem.

I want to restart the scene to restart the game, to play again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My approach might take some time on restructuring things, but it surely makes things really simple and convenient to deal with in the long run. You would have all your logic contained inside one object called **Game**. It is separated from the OpenGL code which is stored inside the **Window**. Every time you need to restart the game you simply destroy Game and create a band new Game object.

[image]

```
class Window {
    //...
};

class Game {
public:
    update(Window* window) {
        window->draw(_object);
    }

private:
    SomeObject _object;
};

// Application
int main() {
    Window* window = new Window();
    Game* game = new Game();

    bool isRestartKeyDown = false;

    while(true) {
        game->update(window);

        if(isRestartKeyDown) {
            delete game;
            game = new Game();
        }
    }
    delete game;
    delete window;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is a good aproach but the probl is that I don't know anything about c++ :/ and I have few time to delivery the game project.. I made a function called respawn that resets all the var values and render the scene and draw the rectangle but when its called only appears the scene without my moving rectangle

Comment: If time is tight then hack away! Let me just advise that you set functions such as `glutKeyboardFunc` and `glutTimerFunc` only once inside main. Keep all relevant behavior in single functions and use switch states accordingly.